# Why won't my Interstitial Ads work in my GameScene but work in the GameViewController in Swift?

Tags: xcode, swift, facebook, ads, interstitial

I have these facebook interstitial ads and when I call them in my GameScene they dont show up. They work perfectly when I call them in the GameViewController but not in my GameScene. Can someone tell me what Im doing wrong with my code?

```
//GameViewController.swift

class GameViewController: UIViewController, FBInterstitialAdDelegate {
let interstitialFBAD: FBInterstitialAd = FBInterstitialAd(placementID: "65543456456456_454345345454534")


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

//CALL THIS IN MY GAMESCENE. 
func loadFBInterstitialAd() {
interstitialFBAD.delegate = self
interstitialFBAD.loadAd()
}

func interstitialAdDidLoad(interstitialAd: FBInterstitialAd!) {
    interstitialFBAD.showAdFromRootViewController(self)
}

//GameScene.swift

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)

        if node.name == "retry" {

            GameViewController().loadFBInterstitialAd()
        }
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `viewDidLoad` of GameViewController register for a notification, and later from the GameScene post a notification when you want the ad to appear.

so your `viewDidLoad` will have the following extra line

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "loadFBInterstitialAd", name: "loadAd", object: nil)
```

then write a method in Gamescene

```
func showAdNow() {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("loadAd", object: nil)
}
```

now in Gamescene.swift replace the line

```
GameViewController().loadFBInterstitialAd()
```

with

```
showAdNow()
```

Comment: Okay so I tried your code but the ads still dont pop up and I get this warning in the console: Warning: Attempt to present <FBInterstitialAdInternal: 0x1409854d0>  on <RacingGame.GameViewController: 0x13f674520> which is already presenting <UIActivityViewController: 0x140ba8d80>

Comment: Bounty if your problem got resolved. As far as the `UIActivityController` warning, are you showing the `UIActivityController`? If so make sure it is dismissed before attempting to present the ad.

Comment: I dont get that warning anymore. I tried giving you the bountry earlier but I had to wait 6 hours. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You try:

```
    //GameViewController.swift
class GameViewController: UIViewController, FBInterstitialAdDelegate {
let interstitialFBAD: FBInterstitialAd = FBInterstitialAd(placementID: "65543456456456_454345345454534")

var scene: GameScene!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let skView = view as! SKView
    skView.multipleTouchEnabled = false
    scene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
    scene.view?.userInteractionEnabled = true
    skView.presentScene(scene)
    scene.gvcDelegate = self
}

    //GameScene.swift
class GameScene: SKScene {
    gvcDelegate: GameViewController?
    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)
        if node.name == "retry" {
            gvcDelegate.loadFBInterstitialAd()
        }
      }
    }
```

Goodluck!

Comment: Okay ill try it out now.

Comment: gvcdelegate is replaced GameViewController

Comment: okay I did that but the ad doesnt show when I press on the button.